# Vim "smartoutdent" for Python?

Tags: vim

I use do auto indenting follow lines that begin with python keywords in Vim using this command.

```
autocmd BufRead *.py  set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,...
```

Is there a way to do a "smartoutdent" for keywords like return or break?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
filetype indent on
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent
```

and it automatically back-indents after statements such as `return`, `break` and `continue`.

I'm not sure if all are necessary, or if it meets your requirements of "smartoutdent", but perhaps it will help.

Comment: The first line isn't necessary. The second line turns `filetype indent` on too. You're also not using autoindent if you're using filetype indent. Summary: use only the second line and you'll be good for all filetypes `vim` knows about.